# index.php in url for just channel pages

Tags: url, config

I have followed the instructions for removing index.php and it works on all pages with the exception of pages with channels. So I would see http://www.example.com/index.php?p=news/2016/news-title.

I also added the `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true`, in the `general.php` file.

Here is what I have in my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you using Craft's stock `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Ive revised my answer to show what I have in there.

Comment: Is the 2nd block "Options +FollowSymLinks" just a SE formatting issue, or is that part of the same .htaccess code in the first chunk?

Comment: ya it's a redirect for the www

Comment: Try moving the www rewrite rule above the Craft rewrite.

Comment: yup that did the trick!

Comment: Awesome... would you mind adding that as an official answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I needed to have the "Options +FollowSymLinks" block above the craft rewrite rule in my htaccess. See comments above.